# Switching characters in my enigma project

Tags: c#, encryption

So, this is going to be less about the specific code that I've written, and more of a logical problem that comes up in my program's design. The program is basically my version of the enigma machine.

First of all, it works, kind of. I just finished adding the last feature, which is a simulation of the machine's plug board; which adds a character pair that are switched during the encryption, and this is where the problem is.

Lets say that I encrypted the word TANIA. It comes out as GIAKE.

So far so good. But then I add a switch; A => I. The encryption works correctly but when I decrypt what happens is that it tries to reverse the process. The A's in TANIA come out correct, but the I is turned into an A.

See the problem?

The decryption process cannot differentiate between the I's that were switched and those that were not. The way it works under the hood, is that the letters are switched before the normal process.

So TANIA is turned into TINII, by the switch. Then it encrypts it normally. When it decrypts it comes up with the word TINII, like it should, but then the switch turns the I's, coming up with the word TANAA.

I hope was able to be clear about this. I've been thinking how to alter the process, but in the end, the same switching problem persists. Does anybody have an idea how to fix this?

I can provide the code itself but I figured it might not be necessary. Though please do tell if you actually want to see it. Just did not want to flood my post.

**EDIT:**
After a couple of replies, decided to add a description of the process and links to the code itself.

Each character in the string is processed individually, and each character runs through the whole process before the program moves onto the next one. So T would encrypted first, then A, and then N, and so on.

The process itself looks like this:

```
SWITCHES -> ROTOR 1 -> ROTOR 2 - ROTOR 3 -> OUTPUT
```

Decrypting functions the same way, except simply in reverse

```
ROTOR 3 -> ROTOR 2 -> ROTOR 1 -> SWITCHES -> OUTPUT
```

The rotors are turned after each letter is processed. The first turns with every character, the second after the first has done a full cycle, and the third after the second has done a full cycle.

The rotors themselves are just objects, holding scrambled alphabets.

So, as an example, if we were to just encrypt the letter T, with a Switch T => U. Inside the program, it would look like this.

```
T switched to U -> U becomes G -> G becomes K -> K becomes C -> output is C.
```

This cycle is run for each character at a time.

The code:

Enigma.cs
http://pastebin.com/E3Ytxdg6 (this is the actual work horse)

RotorSets.cs
http://pastebin.com/7U6TiP9a

I apologize for pasting the whole code, but I couldn't think of which parts to paste that would demonstrate the problem. My earlier description still seems the best way to describe the problem itself.

In the end the code is not very big, but simply looks big because VS wants to format every bracket onto its own line, and because I like writing a lot of comments.

Comment: Post the relevant part of the code that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: It seems like the problem is that you're applying the character replacements one at a time, for the whole string each time, when what you need to do is, one character at a time, apply all the replacements.  That is, if I understand what you're trying to do, which I'm not sure I do.

Comment: Thank you for the replies. I edited the original post with more clarifications and links to the code. I hope I made better sense about what I'm trying to do and what the problem is.